# What happens if supernova undergoes in tightly close multi stars system

Tags: supernova, binary-star, star-formation, multiple-star-systems

I do wonder in a tight or close orbital binary stars or multi stars system, if one stars undergoes supernova and that blast can lead another stars in the system to become supernova, too?

Is there anything like chain-supernova happened in observable universe?

Comment: I don't think so, since a supernova is the result of the gravitational collapse of the core of the star, this shouldn't really effect the collapse of its companion(s). But maybe someone else knows of some special case.